# I want to add satalite map to java swing application using JXMapKit

Tags: java, dictionary, swingx

peace be upon you all

i want to make a java application that contain a map and controlling that map

i mad the most of that but i have a problem

i used JXMapKit.class

i already showing the map on my application now and controlling it as i want

the only problem with me that i want to change the map server

i not want to use OpenStreet map

that is , i want use another map like as satellite map or any map more clear

i do not know how to make that :(

i trying from that link : http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/11/13/mapping-mashups-with-jxmapviewer.html

but really i tired i spend a lot of time making that and i did not achieved what i want

any one know a bout that ?